# Rails - Including Static HTML Snippet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, can we have some GLOBAL static HTML snippets that we can use in the same way as a helper just like include in php? I'm making a nav bar but sometimes I want it at the bottom of my page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

Create a view which its filename starts with an underscore, for example: /views/shared/_navbar.html.erb

then you can render this partial anywhere you'd like using

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/navbar" %>
```

in your view.

Note that although the partial file name has an underscore in the beginning, the render states its name with the underscore omitted.